# Can't get the next line using next() in a loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, iterator, iteration

I'm trying to write a code that iterates through a txt file and only gets the lines I want to print them out.

the text file should look like so:

```
mimi
passwordmimi
mimi johnson
somejob
joji
passwordjoji
jojo
somejob
john
passwordjohn
jonathan
somejob
....
```

and so on. this text file contains basically a user information (for a log in). I need to make everyone's username print out and their real name (ex: mimi and mimi johnson.) and only those. I don't want the current user's info to print out (in this ex: joji)

here is my code:

```
username="joji"

file=open("username.txt","r") 
x=file.readlines()

x=[item.rstrip('\n') for item in x]

x=iter(x)

for line in x:
      if line==username:
              next(x,None)
              next(x,None)
              next(x,None)
      else:
              print line + " username"    ****username should print out. ex:mimi or john
              next(x,None)
              print line +" real name   ****real name should print out. ex: mimi johnson or jonathan
```

for whatever reason when I run this program and i print out the second **** i put, it prints out the username's twice. (so ex:

```
mimi username
mimi real name
mimi johnson username
mimi johnson real name
john username
john real name
jonathan username
jonathan real name
....
```

why is that? it should print out

```
mimi username
mimi johnson real name
john username
jonathan realname 
...
```

if someone could help me out i'd be really grateful i dont get python.
Im also open to any other suggestions to do this.

EDIT::: i tried making a change with a suggestion this is the outcome:

new block of code:

```
else: 
      print line + "username" 
      line =next(x,None)
      print line
```

this is the new outcome:

```
 mimi username
 passmimi real name
 mimi johnson username
 somejob real name
 john username
 passjohn real name
 jonathan username
 somejob real name(***im assuming this one is from john's job)
```

:/ its not doing what its supposed to

Comment: Calling `next()` does not change the value of `line`.

Comment: it doesn't? then what would be the best way

Comment: I think you need to capture the return value of `next` in that case. e.g. `line = next(x)`

Comment: i tried doing that (just adding a line=next(x) right after the first print out for the username) but it gives me not what i want? like it gives me the line it is skipping. and if i add a extra next() to get the line i want, it screws up the whole iteration. is there a better way to iterate and skip lines i dont want other than next? im open to suggestions

Comment: "it gives me the line it is skipping" What do you mean by this? Can you edit your question with the suggested changes and show the output just like you did in your original question?

Comment: alright give me a second

Comment: ok it's done. as you can see it gives me the line previous to what i want

Comment: Do you want to skip the passwords and jobs? If so, you just need to call `next()` at the appropriate times to do so.

Comment: On a side note, `x=iter(x)` is probably not a good idea because you are using the same variable for two different purposes. You should create a new variable here `i = iter(x)`. Also, `x` and `i` are terrible variable names. You should use more descriptive names.

Comment: well thats the thing because the for loop iterates once already i dont know where i should place the next() anymore. I put 3 inside of the if statement to pass over the user i dont want. and then the for loop iterates once. and then i print out the username i want. use next() to skip over the password. n then i wanted to print out the real name. but you're telling me next() doesnt change line itself. if I add a extra next() to do line=next() to get the real name, it'll mess up the whole loop :/

Comment: ill keep that in mind (for the variable names) it's just my way of making it quicker to code because I was doing this only for myself sorry!

Comment: is there a better way to iterate through a loop n skip over things i dont want in the way i made it? it's fine if i can't use next(). i just dont know how to do it.

Comment: I suggest you back up away from the computer. Get out a pencil and piece of paper and write **in English** the steps needed to solve this problem. I think that will help you see the changes you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using regex to parse this file:

```
import re

# regex expression to parse the file as you provided it
# you could access the parseddata as a dict using the 
# keys "username", "password", "real_name" and "job"
ex = "\n*(?P<username>.+)\n(?P<password>.+)\n(?P<real_name>.+)\n(?P<job>.+)[\n\$]"

with open("usernames.txt", 'r') as users:
    matches = re.finditer(ex, users.read())
    for match in matches:
        user = match.groupdict()  # user is a dict

        # print username and real name
        print(user['username'], "username", user['real_name'], "real name")
```

---

**Edit**: I figured that regex was not really needed here as the format of this file is quite simple. So here is the same thing without using regex.

```
def parse(usersfile):
    # strip line break characters
    lines = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in usersfile)

    # keys to be used in the dictionnary
    keys = ('username', 'password', 'real_name', 'job')

    while True:
        # build the user dictionnary with the keys above
        user = {key: line for key, line in zip(keys, lines)}

        # yield user if all the keys are in the dict
        if len(user) == len(keys):
            yield user
        else:  # stop the loop
            break

with open("usernames.txt", 'r') as usersfile:
    for user in parse(usersfile):
        # print username and real name
        print(user['username'], "username", user['real_name'], "real name")
```

Comment: does this assume i have username and password in front of the items in the list? ( as in in the text file)

Comment: It assumes that the first line is the username and the second is the password, the third is the real name and the fourth is the job. If this is what you mean then yes. ;)

Comment: omg i cant read. thank u so much im gonna loop up the whole re thing and learn from this code!

Comment: i tried running your code just to see the outcome and how it works and it gave me a error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make1.py", line 9, in <module>
    matches = re.finditer(ex, users)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: yes I just noticed that I forgot to read() the file, editing my answer

Comment: sorry i dont wanna be a bother but could you explain to me the pattern (ex) that you wrote ><'' not sure what ?P and [\n\$] does. thank you!

Comment: (?P<...>...) is a named pattern what's between "<" and ">" is the name of the pattern that will be accessible in the dictionnary that you get when calling groupdict(). [\n\$] matches either a line break '\n' or the end of the string '\$'

Comment: maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/rS9hN9/1) could help too, it explains everything in this expression

Comment: oh ok so ?P kinda declares a pattern? also why did you use read() and not readline()? i tried using readline() just to see and it doesn't work

Comment: oh wow thank you for the site! last question: is the .* needed at the end of the <> because i want it to continue capturing the rest of the matches?

Comment: ALSO: hash your passwords. Never store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: read() reads the whole file directly which is what's needed for re. Do you mean that it doesn't return all the matches?

Comment: I just added a solution that doesn't use regex to my answer too, it does the same thing as the regex solution using a generator (the `parse` function)